# How can I select enclosing quotes with TextMate?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

In Textmate I can "Select Enclosing Brackets" with `Command+Shift+B`:

[image]

How can I set up a similar keyboard shortcut to select everything between the single / double quotes which encompass the cursor?

Desired Result:

[image: Picture 1.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TextMate 2 you can use Ctrl+Option+B (Select Current Scope) to do this. Note this will include the quotes in the selection, which is slightly different from what you have pictured, but if what you want is to replace the contents you can just hit delete, one quote and then type.

Once you have the selection you can also use Ctrl-Shift-' to toggle the types of quotes surrounding the string, very handy.

I'm not sure if these are present in TextMate 1 as well.

Comment: thank you! although I loved textmate the stagnation in development caused me to move to [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) :)

Comment: Understood - I was there with you but [TextMate 2 is now being updated very regularly](https://github.com/textmate/textmate). May be worth another look.